# Dropdown de Bootstrap no funciona en Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap

He revisado las dependencias y parece que tengo todo puesto alli, pero por alguna razon el dropdown sale de esta manera. Debería salir hacia abajo pero no lo hace, intente usar el ejemplo de Bootstrap y muestra el botón pero no el dropdown en si

[image: Sale de esta manera]

Tengo el código estructurado de esta manera en partials.master. Pooper.js si esta incluido en las dependencias, pero por alguna razón no hace que el dropdown funcione, simplemente muestra los items al lado y no debajo al darle click.

```
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>@yield('title')</title> <!--Obtiene el titulo del archivo PHP el cuel esta-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script defer src="https://friconix.com/cdn/friconix.js"></script>
  <link href="{{ URL::to('src/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
  @yield('styles') <!--Obtiene el css de arriba-->
</head>

<body>
@include('partials.header') <!--Obtiene la barra de navegacion -->

<div class="container">
@yield('content') <!--Coloca lo que se encuentre con la tag contenido en la pagina -->
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

@yield('scripts') <!--Coloca los scripts de bootstrap -->

</body>

</html>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en el archivo del shopping cart, tengo problemas en la parte que dice ul class dropdown en adelante

```
@extends('layouts.master') 

@section('title')
 Shopping Cart
@endsection

@section('content')
<br></br>
  @if(Session::has('cart'))
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
       <ul class="list-group">
         @foreach($products as $product)
           <li class="list-group-item">
             <span class="badge">{{ $product['qty'] }}</span>
             <strong>{{ $product['item']['title'] }}</strong>
             <span class="label label-success">{{ $product['price'] }}</span>
             <div class="btn-group">
             <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" 
             data-toggle="dropdown">Opcion <span class="caret"></span></button>
             <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Reducir por 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Quitar todo</a></li>
              </ul>
             </div>
           </li>
         @endforeach
       </ul>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
      <strong>Total: {{ $totalPrice }}</strong>
      </div>
   </div>

   <hr></hr>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Checkout</button>
      </div>
   </div>
  @else
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
      <h2>NO TIENES PRODUCTOS</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
  @endif
@endsection
```

Comment: Intentaste iniciarlos con '$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()?

Comment: Seguro que no tiene nada que ver con Laravel. Publicá el código HTML generado, no el Blade. De hecho lo ideal sería que crees un snippet funcional para que podamos probar y ver donde está el problema. Con una imagen y un código que no hace nada, es difícil ayudarte. Probá poner todo el dropdown fuera del `.list-group` tal vez algo de esa clase está molestando.

Comment: Intente colocar el dropdown fuera del listo group y no funciono

Comment: el mismo error pero le puse los css y js de la pagina de bootstrap y me dio normal